# How to change a continuous legend without creating break points?

Tags: r, plot, raster, terra

[image: Raster plot]

This is a mean annual temperature map in Celsius/10. It was downloaded from https://envicloud.wsl.ch/#/?prefix=chelsa%2Fchelsa_V1.

I tried this:

```
min_val <- -15000
max_val <- 0

plot(r, col = rev(terrain.colors(10)), at = seq(min_val, max_val, length.out = 11))
```

But it only creates break points. The map looks the same, the only difference is that it creates 9 break points in the legend so I don't have a gradient in color in the legend anymore.

This doesn't work either:

```
plot(r, range=c(-20000, 0))
```

It gives a blank plot.

This also gives me a blank plot:

```
min_val <- -10
max_val <- 0
plot(r, range=c(min_val, max_val))
```

Comment: What is it that you expect to see? Your raster evidently is composed of values close to 0. What do you see if you change `min_val` to -10 and run the code again?

Comment: I expect to see the differnece in mean temperature across Europe. When I changed min_val to -10 in the first piece of code I get the same entire green map with a legend with only 9 colours (instead of a gradient so I guess it creates unnecessary break points and nothing else). I added a third example of code that doesn't work ether.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but what are the ranges of the actual temperatures in your data set?

Comment: I downloaded it from https://envicloud.wsl.ch/#/?prefix=chelsa%2Fchelsa_V1. It's the mean annual temperature (C/10) but I'm starting to think that there is something wrong because the scale doesn't make sense (from 0 to -10000?)